# Intermitent load from WEB-INF/lib/*.jar!/META-INF/resources

Tags: tomcat, gwt, resources, embedded-jetty, gwt-super-dev-mode

I'm working with a GWT project and I have a library (jar) where there are several static resources in `META-INF/resources` folder which should be served.

It works well when I deploy the application in *Tomcat*, but when I try to run it with **SuperDevMode**, it means with the embedded *Jetty* which comes with GWT,  the resources aren't loaded well, I'm getting this ***intermittent*** error:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: zip file closed
```

So it means that sometimes the resources are loaded but most of the time they aren't.

I've read that it would work if I disable ***gzip*** compression in *Jetty*, but actually I didn't find a way to configure the embedded *Jetty* in GWT.

I tried also to run the application with *Tomcat* in development mode but I lost the GWT debugging capabilities.

Has anyone worked with this successfully?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you run Tomcat in debug mode, debugging should still work:

Right-click Tomcat-Server entry in Servers view in eclipse and then "Debug".
 After that server side debugging is done using Tomcat, client side using super dev mode.

If you are not using eclipse, it might depend on your development environment - but still it should be possible to debug the server side code.

Comment: Yes you right, but I was talking about debugging GWT code.